# howto debug nuxt instance unavailable?

Tags: nuxtjs3

i'm working on a nuxt 3 project.

i've created a composable useAvailabilityRoom.ts but suddendy, it stopped working to throw this error :

```bash
    Error: nuxt instance unavailable  10:42:04
        at Module.useNuxtApp (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.mjs:165:13)
        at Module.useAsyncData (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/asyncData.mjs:24:38)
        at Module.useFetch (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/fetch.mjs:52:43)
        at Module.__vite_ssr_exports__.default (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/composables/useUsers.ts:6:55)
        at Module.__vite_ssr_exports__.default (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/composables/useRoomAvailability.ts:61:55)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async setup (/Users/chilperic/Sites/cabinetpartage/pages/salles/[idLocation]/[idRoom].vue:59:12)
```

#### my call in page component

```js
    try {
        const roomAvailability = await useRoomAvailability(route.params.idRoom);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

#### my composable code

```js
    class RoomSchedule {
       roomId: String = "";
        days = [
            "monday",
            "tuesday",
            "wednesday",
            "thursday",
            "friday",
            "saturday",
            "sunday",
        ];
        monday = [];
        tuesday = [];
        wednesday = [];
        thursday = [];
        friday = [];
        saturday = [];
        sunday = [];

        constructor(roomId: String) {
            this.roomId = roomId;
        }

        checkAvailability(profile) {
            for (let d in this.days) {
                if (
                    profile.weekly_schedule[this.days[d]] !== false &&
                    profile.weekly_schedule[this.days[d]][this.roomId] !==
                        undefined &&
                    profile.weekly_schedule[this.days[d]][this.roomId] == true
                ) {
                    // on crée un objet de rendez-vous
                    const apt = {
                        begins_at: "07:00",
                        ends_at: "20:00",
                        name: profile.first_name + " " + profile.last_name,
                        job: profile.job,
                        user: profile.user_id,
                    };
                    // on compare les deux objets pour ne pas insérer un doublon
                    if (
                        this[this.days[d]].find(
                            (element) =>
                                JSON.stringify(element) === JSON.stringify(apt)
                        ) == undefined
                    ) {
                        this[this.days[d]].push({
                            begins_at: "07:00",
                            ends_at: "20:00",
                            name: profile.first_name + " " + profile.last_name,
                            job: profile.job,
                            user: profile.user_id,
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    // console.log("rien pour " + this.days[d]);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    export default async (roomId: String) => {
        // récupérer la dispo de la salle
        const locationsObject = await useLocations();
        const locations = Object.values({ ...locationsObject });

        const room = locations.filter((el) => el.identifier == roomId);
        const roomAvailability = toRaw(room[0]).availability;

        let Schedule = new RoomSchedule(roomId);

        // récupérer les résa des thérapeutes en bail
        const profiles = await useUsers();

        for (let av in profiles) {
            // on parcourt les jours et on regarde s'il y a des thérapeutes au bail
            for (let day in profiles[av].weekly_schedule) {
                await Schedule.checkAvailability(profiles[av]);
            }
        }

        return Schedule;
    };
```

If i log the checkAvailability content, i have the right data.
I don't understand how to fix this error. Hope you can see what's wrong.

Comment: I sadly can't see what all the submodules of your posted code-snippet do but I am pretty confident that what's happening here is the same issue that I had a few days as well. Check out [my solution to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76033170/13482004](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76033170/13482004)